# nodemailer and gmail APIs

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, nodemailer

Im trying to get nodemailer working using Google GMail API.
I've got my Google project set up - using their oauth sandbox for redirect,
I've got a clientID, secret and refresh token from my developers console.

The Code

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');

// create reusable transporter
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
        service: 'gmail',
        xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
            user: 'me@myDomain.com',
            clientid: 'blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            clientSecret: 'k33p-gUeSsINg',
            refreshToken: '123BritneyIsTheBest'
        }),
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    } );

// setup email data
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'me@myDomain.com',
    to: 'me@yahoo.com',
    subject: 'Hello there Google API...',
    text: 'Hello Google API',
    html: '<b>Hello Google API</b>'
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ', info.messageId);
});
```

The Error.

```
{ 
    Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l24sm4075119ywk.21 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\abc\index.js:591:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (C:\abc\index.js:1350:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\abc\index.js:840:18)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\abc\index.js:747:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\abc\index.js:543:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\abc\index.js:495:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    code: 'EENVELOPE',
    response: '530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l24sm4075119ywk.21 - gsmtp',
    responseCode: 530,
    command: 'MAIL FROM' 
}
```

I have tried this - and it works, but it's my understanding that this is very unsecured and NOT acceptable for production.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'me@myDomain.com',
        pass: 'Seriously?'
    }
});

... all the rest is the same, removed for brevity...
```

The existing posts solutions have not helped.
Thank You

Comment: For production, I would suggest using [OAuth2 implementation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/) for logging in. You can also check the [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) for additional reference.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification?

### From :

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
        service: 'gmail',
        xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
            user: 'me@myDomain.com',
            clientid: 'blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            clientSecret: 'k33p-gUeSsINg',
            refreshToken: '123BritneyIsTheBest'
        }),
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    } );
```

### To :

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        type: 'oauth2',
        user: 'me@myDomain.com',
        clientId: 'blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com', // This key is "clientId".
        clientSecret: 'k33p-gUeSsINg',
        refreshToken: '123BritneyIsTheBest'
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});
```

### Note :

- Please confirm whether `https://mail.google.com/` was included in the scope, when you retrieved the refresh token.
- Please confirm whether gmail API is enabled.
- It may be required to turn on "Allow less secure apps: ON" at https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps.

### Reference :

- [nodemailer OAuth2](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/)

In my environment, I confirmed that this works fine. But if this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately, I'll have to try combinations of the options you describe, but for now I'm using the "unsafe" way, to get thru my demo. Thank you. I'm sure I'll pick this up again soon.

Comment: @jpmyob I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the error messages, when you run this script? By knowing the error messages, it might help to think of the solution.